# Анимация слов на HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, css-animation

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать на HTML, CSS, JS так, чтобы курсор "|" когда возвращается налево он заменял слово  на другое + на новый "цвет"-"background-color" и потом через 5 секунд снова возращялся направо и изменял всё. Вот как то так: (код я ещё не дописала, потому что не пойму как, нигде в интернете ответ найти не могу. Заранее спасибо!)

Эффект должен выглять как на картинке, но вместо картинок долны быть слова:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.is-animated {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255, 146, 246, 0.651);
}
.is-animated span {
  display: block;
}
.property {
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: right;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation-name: expandProperty;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandProperty {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="property is-animated">
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
let words = [
  "text1",
  "text2",
  "text3",
  "text4",
  "text5",
  "text6",
  "text7"
];
let colors = [
  "#0a009d",
  "#f91d92",
  "#38bc4c",
  "#ffce1e",
  "#00bbf9 ",
  "#9f2dd4",
  "#19ddbf",
];
let currentWord = 0;
let intervalid = setInterval(()=>{
  if (currentWord == words.length - 1)
    currentWord = 0;
  else
    currentWord++;
  let obj = document.getElementById("word");
  obj.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentWord];
  obj.innerText = words[currentWord];
}, 600);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.is-animated {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255, 146, 246, 0.651);
}
.is-animated span {
  display: block;
}
.property {
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: right;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation-name: expandProperty;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation : expandProperty 10s infinite forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandProperty {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

    


@keyframes expandProperty {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="property is-animated">
      <span id="word">text</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите анимировать несколько строк, без JS будет тяжко, придётся высчитывать таймлайн вручную, например как в примере:

```css
.print-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.print-text-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: '';
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: none 12s step-end infinite; /* Вся анимация будет выполняться 12 секунд */
}

.print-text-item--1 {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  animation-name: print-1; /* Каждый элемент со своей анимацией, которая разбита по таймлайну, чтобы имитировать задержку и воспроизводить анимацию зациклено */
}

.print-text-item--2 {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  animation-name: print-2;
}

.print-text-item--3 {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000;
  animation-name: print-3;
}

.print-text-cr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: cr 1s step-end infinite;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

@keyframes cr {
  0%, 100% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 1;}
}

/*
  Везде используется animation-timing-function: step-end, чтобы анимация больше похожа была на печать.
  Для этого весь тайлайн разбит на куски, на каждую букву свой отдельный "участок".
*/

@keyframes print-1 { /* в слове HTML - 4 буквы */
  2.5%, 27.5% {width: 1ch;}
  5%, 25% {width: 2ch;}
  7.5%, 22.5% {width: 3ch;}
  10%, 20% {width: 4ch;}
  0%, 30%, 100% {width: 0;}
}

@keyframes print-2 { /* в слове CSS - 3 буквы */
  32.5%, 57.5% {width: 1ch;}
  35%, 55% {width: 2ch;}
  37.5%, 52.5% {width: 3ch;}
  0%, 60%, 100% {width: 0;}
}


@keyframes print-3 { /* в слове JAVASCRIPT - 10 буквы */
  61%, 89% {width: 1ch;}
  62%, 88% {width: 2ch;}
  63%, 87% {width: 3ch;}
  64%, 86% {width: 4ch;}
  65%, 85% {width: 5ch;}
  66%, 84% {width: 6ch;}
  67%, 83% {width: 7ch;}
  68%, 82% {width: 8ch;}
  69%, 81% {width: 9ch;}
  70%, 80% {width: 10ch;}
  0%, 90%, 100% {width: 0;}
}

/* 
  Так же, чтобы исключить разную ширину символов - используется monospace шрифт (одинаковая ширина символов) и единица измерения CH (загуглить).
*/
```

```html
<div class="print-text">
  <span class="print-text-item print-text-item--1"><span>HTML</span></span>
  <span class="print-text-item print-text-item--2"><span>CSS</span></span>
  <span class="print-text-item print-text-item--3"><span>JavaScript</span></span>
  <span class="print-text-cr"></span>
</div>
```

---

По этому лучше заюзать JS.

Например так: (первое что пришло в сонную голову)

```js
var symTick = 100; // Сколько мс выделяется на 1 букву.
var delay = 500;
var active = 0; // Какой текст воспроизводится
var buffer = [];
var printTextItem = document.querySelectorAll('.print-text-item');

printTextItem.forEach(function(item) {
  var text = item.textContent.trim();
  buffer.push({
    len: text.length,
    text: text,
    cls: item.classList
  });
  item.remove();
});

StartPrint(document.querySelector('.print-text'), active);

function StartPrint(parent, index) {
  parent.innerHTML = '';
  var data = buffer[index];
  var i = 0;
  var el = document.createElement('span');
  el.classList = data.cls;
  parent.append(el);
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(i < data.len) {
      el.textContent += data.text[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
      setTimeout(DeleteTextTick, delay);
    }
  }, symTick);

  function DeleteTextTick() {
    i = 0;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      if(i < data.len) {
        el.textContent = el.textContent.slice(0, -1);
        console.info(el.textContent);
        i++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        active = active + 1 < buffer.length ? active + 1 : 0;
        setTimeout(StartPrint(parent, active), delay);
      }
    }, symTick / 2);
  }
}
```

```css
.print-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.print-text::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: .1ch;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: cr 1s step-end infinite;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-left: .3ch;
}

.print-text-item.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.print-text-item.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.print-text-item.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000;
}

@keyframes cr {
  0%, 100% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="print-text">
  <span class="print-text-item red">HTML</span>
  <span class="print-text-item blue">CSS</span>
  <span class="print-text-item yellow">JavaScript</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Я хотела чтобы когда курсор возвращается налево тоже появлялось новое слово. Получается курсор меняет слова когда он передвигается и налево, и направо. Но всё равно спасибо.)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант использовать js функцию `setInterval` и устанавливать нужный вам стиль.

Если через css, можно как-то так:

```
  animation: expandProperty 10s infinite forwards;


@keyframes expandProperty {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: У меня не получается перенести слова "text2","text4","text6" направо, они у меня просто мигают. Подскажите пожалуйсто как переместить их справо от курсора. Спасибо за Ваш ответ (Я добавила свой новый код сверху и пример с картинкой который более точнее описывает, что я хочу получить)